# react-native-tab-view dismount previous scene

Tags: react-native

Currently i'm using this script to render scenes:

```
const renderScene = ({ route }) => {
  switch (route.key) {
    case FirstScene:
      return <FirstComponent />;
    case SecondScene:
      return <SecondComponent />;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};
```

But when i'm on FirstScene for example, SecondComponent is rendered as well and it's doing some fetching on data etc etc. How to prevent that if i'm on first scene i want to have only the first component active at the time

Component:

```
<TabView
          lazy
          navigationState={{ index, routes }}
          renderScene={renderScene}
          initialLayout={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width }}
          onIndexChange={setIndex}
          renderTabBar={(props) => (
            <TabBar
              {...props}
              style={{
                backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
                height: 32,
                borderBottomWidth: 0,
                shadowOffset: { height: 0, width: 0 },
                shadowOpacity: 0,
                shadowRadius: 0,
                marginBottom: 12,
              }}
              indicatorStyle={{ height: 0 }}
              activeColor="textlight.accent"
              inactiveColor="textlight.secondary"
              renderIndicator={(props: TabBarIndicatorProps<ITabProps>) => (
                <TabBarIndicator
                  {...props}
                  style={{
                    height: 32,
                    backgroundColor: 'white',
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                  }}
                />
              )}
              renderTabBarItem={(props: TabBarItemProps<ITabProps>) => (
                <TabBarItem
                  {...props}
                  activeColor="primary.600"
                  style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-start', marginTop: -2 }}
                  renderLabel={({ route, color }) => (
                    <Text color={color} size="sm" fontWeight={600} marginBottom={30}>
                      {route.title}
                    </Text>
                  )}
                />
              )}
            />
          )}
        />
```

Comment: Have you tried lazyLoading of the component?

Comment: in the TabView component add the `lazy` prop

Comment: but this works just the first time? when i go from component #1 to component #2 and then get back from #2 to #1, #2 keeps fetching

Comment: edited post with the component usage